# How to Connect to a Google Cloud SQL Instance from a Different Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I need your help! I'm trying to connect to the Google Cloud SQL instance from a different server (ie.,provided through Hostgator) but I am unable to select the Database (which is already created at Google Cloud SQL) using the mySQL function - "mysql_select_db" in order to store and retrieve data from my application running at Hostgator webhost.

This is the error that I'm getting

[image: mySQL error]

Here's the code which am using

[image: PHP code]

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

**Update**

After correcting the mysql_select_db() function, I'm able to select and insert into the DB table but when I try to retrieve and count the number of rows in the table, I get the following warning

[image: Warning]

This is the code for the same

[image: code]

Here's the code used to insert the record

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO members VALUES(32, 'Sallu')");
```

echo "Row inserted";

Thanks

Comment: I have already authorized the external IP address from where I'm going to connect

Comment: The error is pretty clear, your user is not allowed to access the database. Doble-check the credentials and retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mysqli_connect` but you want to select the database using `mysql_select_db`.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli_* statement

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,"testing");

mysqli_query("YOUR QUERY..",$conn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Arun ... but even after successfully inserting the record into the table, I am unable to retrieve it .. .When I count the no. of rows, I get a "0"

Comment: @Salman Man. Use a bit of your brain. Are you having the first semester in college? The most annoying thing about this, is you didn't accept any of the answers we gave, but your problem is solved. The problem with the returned number of rows is not with the answers, we gave, but with your query. You may want to ask another question or you can learn new stuffs about `SELECT` queries by googling your problem up.

Comment: @KrisztiánDudás I apologize for not accepting the answer as I got stuck up with further queries... P.S It's not my first sem at college but I am unable to get through Google cloud SQL.

Comment: @Salman If you are stuck with queries, you can do the following debug methods: using `or die(mysqli_error($conn);` after every `mysqli_query` calls. This tries to execute the query and if there is an error in the query, it prints that out to the screen. I see you updated your question. The error you get is because, there is an error in your query. You may have `nro` column instead of `rno`. `mysqli_num_rows` gets boolean value because the `mysqli_query` returned false, so the error is in your query. There is nothing seems bad with it, you just simply refer to a wrong column or table.